# Strange situation with image and jsp

Tags: html, image, jsp, struts2

Here is what I did (by the way, I am using Struts2 framework):

1. I have a custom interceptor which generates an image file and saves it under a directory (lets call it `dir1`) under WebContent. The name (relative path) of the file is saved in the session.
2. When the action is called it returns SUCCESS and a certain page gets loaded.
3. In that page I have an `img` tag with 
   `src="<s:property value="#session.filename">"`

Now when the page is loaded, the image does not get loaded. I ran the whole thing multiple times and a lot of images got generated. Then I changed the img attribute to `src="dir1/file1.jpg"` and it works. But then i tried for the other images (file15.jpg, file9.jpg) and the images failed to load again.

Bottom line is: only some images are loaded and some are not even though they are in the same directory.

P.S. I generated the images as BufferedImage object and then used ImageIO.write method to create the image file.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the information provided.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your image generator (the interceptor you mentioned) is not working correctly.

If the images are not loaded even with `<img src="dir1/file15.jpg"/>` it means the browser can not recognize 'dir1/file15.jpg' as a correct image.

Try to see your image with some image viewer program first to make sure that the image file is a correct file.

Comment: I did, and the images are fine. Some of the images worked, but only if I specifically mentioned them in the src attribute of the img tag. But if I use the tag <img src="<s:property value="#session.filename">"> it does not work.
Within the interceptor I sysout the name of the file and also did it within the action, and in both cases it worked,

Comment: I found something which made things relatively "less vague".